# Can't deserialize an array of objects from JSON into a C# object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I'm having trouble getting the JavascriptSerializer to deserialize an array of objects. I'm not terribly sure what I'm missing.

Here's my object...

```
public class HomefinderResult
{
    public Data data;
    public List<Listing> listings;
    public Status status;


    public class Listing
    {
        public string recordingDate;
        public Buyer buyer;
        public double distance;
        public string id;

        public class Buyer
        {
            public Address address;
            public string phone;
            public string firstName;
            public string lastName;

            public class Address
            {
                public string line1;
                public string city;
                public string state;
                public string zip;
                public string county;
                public string latitude;
                public string longitude;

            }
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Meta meta;
        public class Meta
        {
            public int totalMatched;
            public int totalPages;
            public int currentPage;
            public double executionTime;
        }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public int code;
        public string[] errorStack;
    }
}
```

and here's the json response I'm trying to deserialize...

```
     {
     "data":{
        "meta":{
           "totalMatched":126,
           "totalPages":7,
           "currentPage":1,
           "executionTime":0.26153302192688
        },
        "listings":[
         {
            "recordingDate":"2010-06-07",
            "buyer":{
               "address":{
                  "line1":"999 Meadow Rd",
                  "city":"Oak Ridge",
                  "state":"TN",
                  "zip":"99999",
                  "county":"Anderson",
                  "latitude":"99.0316920000",
                  "longitude":"-99.2476320000"
               },
               "phone":"9995551234",
               "firstName":"xxx",
               "lastName":"xxx"
            },
            "distance":18.088793566409,
            "purchasePrice":"975000",
            "id":"70a706d46c5e1db7417b78c159467431"
         },

         {
            "recordingDate":"2010-06-04",
            "buyer":{
               "address":{
                  "line1":"999 Willow Ln",
                  "city":"Oak Ridge",
                  "state":"TN",
                  "zip":"99999",
                  "county":"Anderson",
                  "latitude":"99.0045700000",
                  "longitude":"-99.3182850000"
               },
               "firstName":"xxx",
               "lastName":"xxx",
               "gender":"Female"
            },
            "distance":22.244494041996,
            "purchasePrice":"201000",
            "id":"dda41ec8150c8648a7e9926b2c5fd468"
         }
      ]
   },
   "status":{
      "code":200,
      "errorStack":null
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should not post real data :-p

Comment: Its public record :) You're absolutely right though.

Answer (score 1):

After switching over to JSON.NET and having the same problem, I walked away for a few minutes and came back. I found my problem -- I needed to nest listing inside data, not at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 classes, yet one wrapper so you need a class that wraps the other 3 to match your root "class" level in the JSON.